# Hibernate doesn't store the related entities in SQL server database

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I'm struggling with an issue.
I have the current setup:
-Spring version: 3.2.0.RELEASE
-Hibernate version: 3.5.0-Final
-Tomcat webserver

I'm building an application that stores and fetches Individual objects into an SQL server DB.
I want to make use of the annotations in Hibernate.
I can build my object like I want it, but when I store it, Only the root object is stored, but not it's related objects.

To make the problem a little more simple. I have an Individual object and every individual can haven 0 or more diploma's:

```
@XmlRootElement
@Entity
@Table(name="INDIVIDUALS")
public class Individual {

@Id
@Column(name="SSIN", nullable=false)
private String ssin;

@XmlElementWrapper(name = "healthCareProfessionals")
@XmlElement(name = "healthCareProfessional")
@OneToMany(mappedBy="individual", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<HealthCareProfessional> healthCareProfessionals = new HashSet<>();

@XmlElementWrapper(name = "diplomas")
@XmlElement(name = "diploma")
@OneToMany(mappedBy="individual", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Diploma> diplomas = new HashSet<>();

@Column(name="LAST_NAME")
private String lastName;

@Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
private String firstName;

@Column(name="MIDDLE_NAME")
private String middleName;

@Column(name="SEX")
private Sex sex;

@Column(name="BIRTH_DATE")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateAdapter.class)
private Date birthDate;

@Column(name="DEATH_DATE")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateAdapter.class)
private Date deathDate;

public Individual() {}

public Individual (String ssin, Set<Diploma> diplomas, String firstName, String lastName, String middleName, Sex sex, Date birthDate, Date deathDate) {
    this.ssin = ssin;
    this.healthCareProfessionals = healthCareProfessionals;
    this.diplomas = diplomas;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.middleName = middleName;
    this.sex = sex;
    this.birthDate = birthDate;
    this.deathDate = deathDate;
}

public String getSsin() {
    return ssin;
}

public void setSsin(String ssin) {
    this.ssin = ssin;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getMiddleName() {
    return middleName;
}

public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
    this.middleName = middleName;
}

public Sex getSex() {
    return sex;
}

public void setSex(Sex sex) {
    this.sex = sex;
}

public Set<Diploma> getDiplomas() {
    return diplomas;
}

public void addDiploma(Diploma diploma) {
    this.diplomas.add(diploma);
}

public void addDiplomas(Collection<Diploma> diplomas) {
    if (this.diplomas == null){
        this.diplomas = new HashSet<>() ;
    }
    this.diplomas.addAll(diplomas);

}

public Set<HealthCareProfessional> getHealthCareProfessionals() {
    return healthCareProfessionals;
}

public void addHealthCareProfessional(HealthCareProfessional healthCareProfessional) {
    this.healthCareProfessionals.add(healthCareProfessional);
}
```

The Diploma entity is defined as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="DIPLOMAS", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "DIPLOMA_ID"),
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "CODE")})
public class Diploma {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.TABLE)
@Column(name="DIPLOMA_ID", unique=true, nullable=false)
private int id;

@Column(name="CODE", nullable=false)
private String code;

@Column(name="NAME", nullable=false)
private String name;

@Column(name="OBTAINING_DATE", nullable=false)
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateAdapter.class)
private Date obtainingDate;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="SSIN")
private Individual individual;

public Diploma() {}

public Diploma (String code, String name, Date obtainingDate, Individual individual) {
    this.code = code;
    this.name = name;
    this.obtainingDate = obtainingDate;
    this.individual = individual;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@XmlTransient
public Individual getIndividual() {
    return individual;
}

public void setIndividual(Individual individual) {
    this.individual = individual;
}
```

The tables are created with the correct foreign keys:

```
CREATE TABLE INDIVIDUALS (
SSIN VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
LAST_NAME VARCHAR(255),
FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(255),
MIDDLE_NAME VARCHAR(255),
SEX VARCHAR(10),
BIRTH_DATE DATETIME,
DEATH_DATE DATETIME);

CREATE TABLE DIPLOMAS (
DIPLOMA_ID BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
CODE VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
INDIVIDUAL_ID VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
OBTAINING_DATE DATETIME NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT INDIVIDUAL_FK FOREIGN KEY(INDIVIDUAL_ID) REFERENCES INDIVIDUALS(SSIN));
```

I can build up the Object the object in my application:

```
<individual>
    <healthCareProfessionals>
        <healthCareProfessional>
            <specialityApprovals/>
            <id>0</id>
            <NIHII_number>32030586</NIHII_number>
            <NIHII_qualificationCode>10,001</NIHII_qualificationCode>
            <profession>
                <authenticSource>EHP</authenticSource>
                <code>DENTIST</code>
                <name>Tandarts</name>
                <type>profession type</type>
            </profession>
        </healthCareProfessional>
        <healthCareProfessional>
            <specialityApprovals>
                <specialityApproval>
                    <authenticSource>FPS_PH</authenticSource>
                    <code>MPC3</code>
                    <description>GERIATRIE</description>
                    <type>specialty type</type>
                </specialityApproval>
            </specialityApprovals>
            <id>0</id>
            <NIHII_number>10013368</NIHII_number>
            <NIHII_qualificationCode>10,123</NIHII_qualificationCode>
            <profession>
                <authenticSource>EHP</authenticSource>
                <code>PHYSICIAN</code>
                <name>Geneesheer</name>
                <type>profession type</type>
            </profession>
        </healthCareProfessional>
        <healthCareProfessional>
            <specialityApprovals/>
            <id>0</id>
            <NIHII_number>54049388</NIHII_number>
            <NIHII_qualificationCode>10,001</NIHII_qualificationCode>
            <profession>
                <authenticSource>EHP</authenticSource>
                <code>PHYSIOTHERAPIST</code>
                <name>Fysiotherapeut</name>
                <type>profession type</type>
            </profession>
        </healthCareProfessional>
        <healthCareProfessional>
            <specialityApprovals/>
            <id>0</id>
            <NIHII_number>40003887</NIHII_number>
            <NIHII_qualificationCode>10,123</NIHII_qualificationCode>
            <profession>
                <authenticSource>EHP</authenticSource>
                <code>NURSE</code>
                <name>Verpleegkundige</name>
                <type>profession type</type>
            </profession>
        </healthCareProfessional>
        <healthCareProfessional>
            <specialityApprovals/>
            <id>0</id>
            <NIHII_number>29001416</NIHII_number>
            <NIHII_qualificationCode>10,001</NIHII_qualificationCode>
            <profession>
                <authenticSource>EHP</authenticSource>
                <code>PHARMACIST</code>
                <name>Apotheker</name>
                <type>profession type</type>
            </profession>
        </healthCareProfessional>
    </healthCareProfessionals>
    <diplomas>
        <diploma>
            <code>010EEE</code>
            <id>0</id>
            <name>Diploma arts verkregen in EEE </name>
        </diploma>
        <diploma>
            <code>010EEE</code>
            <id>0</id>
            <name>Diploma arts verkregen in EEE </name>
        </diploma>
        <diploma>
            <code>010EEE</code>
            <id>0</id>
            <name>Diploma arts verkregen in EEE </name>
        </diploma>
        <diploma>
            <code>010EEE</code>
            <id>0</id>
            <name>Diploma arts verkregen in EEE </name>
        </diploma>
        <diploma>
            <code>010EEE</code>
            <id>0</id>
            <name>Diploma arts verkregen in EEE </name>
        </diploma>
        <diploma>
            <code>010EEE</code>
            <id>0</id>
            <name>Diploma arts verkregen in EEE </name>
        </diploma>
        <diploma>
            <code>010EEE</code>
            <id>0</id>
            <name>Diploma arts verkregen in EEE </name>
        </diploma>
        <diploma>
            <code>010EEE</code>
            <id>0</id>
            <name>Diploma arts verkregen in EEE </name>
        </diploma>
    </diplomas>
    <birthDate>1982-05-12</birthDate>
    <firstName>HANNES HANS</firstName>
    <lastName>DE CLERCQ</lastName>
    <sex>male</sex>
    <ssin>67111433946</ssin>
</individual>
```

When I want to store the object, only the values in the INDIVIDUALS table are stored, but not in the DIPLOMAS table...

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong

Here is my applicationContext:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="be.healthconnect.pwg" />
<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
      destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=PWG" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean>

<bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="MyApplicationPersistanceUnitName"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"/>
            <property name="generateDdl" value="false"/>
            <property name="showSql" value="false"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jpaVendorAdaptor"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf" />
</bean>
```

And this is my persistance.xml, that resides in the META-INF folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
         version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">

<persistence-unit name="individual" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>be.healthconnect.pwg.domain.Individual</class>
</persistence-unit>
```

I store the object I constructed using the persist method of the EntityManagerFactory:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void addIndividual(Individual individual) {
   em.persist(individual);
}
```

I would expect the INDIVIDUALS and DIPLOMAS tables to be filled in, but unfortunately only the INDIVIDUALS table is filled in:

[image: Individuals table filled up]

[image: Diplomas table not filled in]

Help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change as below. Individual is on the non-owning (inverse) side of the relationship so you will need to set both sides for cascading to work.

```
public void addDiploma(Diploma diploma) {
    this.diplomas.add(diploma);
    diploma.setIndividual(this);
}
```

On looking again you do not actually appear to have added any cascade options to this relationship so you will also need to add cascade=XYZ to the @OneToMany mapping.

Comment: Hi Alan, thank you so much for your quick reply. I didn't show all my code, but I have a DiplomaBuilder class where I set the Individual to the Diploma. However, your remark about not having added the cascade option appears to be the solution to my problem! I added the Cascade property to my OneToMany mappings and now I get errors about inserting the diploma's, so I think my problem is gone. Can't thank you enough!